# Data extension populated in second step (of automation) not showing for Journey Builder audience

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I am trying to create a journey. The entry source I selected is : Audience -> Automation Studio Audience.

The problem:

The automation has 2 steps

step 1: Import Activity : Pulls data from Salesforce Report into a data extension. Lets call this Data Extension A

Step 2: Query Activity : Filters this data extension and inserts the filtered fat  into another data extension. Lets call this Data Extension B

Now in the journey builder in the 'Select Data Extension' Step I can see only data extension A. It does not show the data extension B which is populated in the second step of the automation activity.

Can someone tell me why this is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is DE B a Sendable one ?

Comment: @Maneesh Yes DE B is a Sendable one

Comment: I tried it just now and it worked for me straightaway. Does your DE have a primary key ?

Comment: Hello Maneesh, I just tried again and it worked. Probably the reason was I had moved the DE that gets populated to a different folder. Now its working fine. Thanks for checking and sorry for that.